# Programmatically define macro within the body of \foreach

Tags: macros, expansion, foreach, xparse

I am trying to write a macro `\RR`, allowing me to type `\mathbb{R}` in text, with an optional parameter for an exponent. The desired functionality is shown below:

```
I can now write \RR\ in text. % --> produces: I can now write $\mathbb{R}$ in text.
Blah blah \RR[m+n] blah blah. % --> produces: Blah blah $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ blah blah
```

For a fixed letter, such as R, this is currently achieved with:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\RR}{o}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}\IfNoValueF{#1}{^{#1}}}}
```

I would like to define similar commands for other letters. I realize the most practical way to do this is to simply write a version of the above for each additional letter. For learning purposes however, I'm curious how I might go about with with `\foreach`. I've tried something along the lines of

```
\foreach \letter in {F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H}{
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname\letter\letter\endcsname{o}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{\letter}\IfNoValueF{#1}{^{#1}}}}
}
```

The above fails to create the command. Trying

```
I can now write \RR\ in text. % --> should produce: I can now write $\mathbb{R}$ in text.
Blah blah \RR[m+n] blah blah. % --> should produce: Blah blah $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ blah blah
```

yields the errors `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@body` at the point of definition (inside the `foreach`) and `Undefined control sequence` when I tried to use `\RR` as shown above.

At the very least, it seems like its missing something like an `\expandafter` or `\noexand` which I've seen used in `\edef` to control the expansion of the `\ensuremath{\mathbb{\letter}\IfNoValueF{#1}{^{#1}}}`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.  The first one, that generates the error, is that `\foreach` does (something equivalent to) `\def\pgffor@body{<loop code>}`, and if `<loop code>` contains a `#`, that will error (try it).  The solution to this one is to double the `#`, so

```latex
\IfNoValueF{##1}{^{##1}}
```

then there will be no errors... but your commands won't work either `:D`

The first roadblock is that `\foreach` creates a group around the loop code, so local assignments are lost and, as you might have guessed by now, `\NewDocumentCommand` creates the command in a local scope (prepending `\global` to it won't work either), so after `\foreach` ends your commands won't exist anymore. `\foreach` is not a good choice to define commands (or programming tasks in general, in my opinion).

The second problem is that your commands are defined as (simplified):

```latex
\def\FF#1{\ensuremath {\mathbb {\letter }\IfNoValueF {#1}{^{#1}}}}
\def\NN#1{\ensuremath {\mathbb {\letter }\IfNoValueF {#1}{^{#1}}}}
\def\ZZ#1{\ensuremath {\mathbb {\letter }\IfNoValueF {#1}{^{#1}}}}
...
```

and what is `\letter`?  Likely `H`, since it's the last value in the loop, but with recent versions of `pgffor` it's undefined (or something you don't expect).

My suggestion to defeat both problems in one go is to not use `\foreach`.  Use instead a looping construct that doesn't do groups, and preferably allows the loop item to be `#1` rather than a macro.  `expl3`'s `\clist_map_inline:nn` fits the bill:

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { #1#1 } { o }
      {\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}\IfNoValueF{##1}{^{##1}}}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(`\exp_args:Nc \macro { <tokens> }` is `\expandafter\macro\csname <tokens>\endcsname`).

Comment: GroupThink :-).

Comment: By four seconds! :)

Comment: and you typed more

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention it but I assume you are using the loop from pgf which places a group around each iteration.  It's easier to use a different construct eg map over the list with expl3.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn{F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H}{
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1#1\endcsname{o}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}\IfNoValueF{##1}{^{##1}}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\FF  \FF[x]

\QQ  \QQ[2]

\ZZ \ZZ[\infty]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have an older latex release you will need to add `\usepackage{xparse}`

Comment: Not enough `zzz` in this answer :(

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik good point, serious omission fixed

Comment: _Much_ better :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, David. `\clist_map_inline:nn` seems super useful going forward.

Comment: `\exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { #1#1 }` has colon and underscore. ;-)

Comment: @egreg but then that would be Phelype's answer. But the idea here was to correct the version in the question with minimal changes to highlight the error, nit to use as much expl3 as possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,listofitems}
\def\ZZstencil#1#2\relax{%
  \mathbb{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else^{#2}\fi
}
\def\ZZargs{[1][]}
\newcommand\makeZZ[1]{%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\z\z\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\ZZargs\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\ZZstencil\z####1\relax}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\makeZZ{F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H}
$\RR$
$\RR[a+b]$
$\ZZ$
$\ZZ[(a+b)/2]$
$\HH$$\HH[x]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need it to `\ensuremath`, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,listofitems}
\def\ZZstencil#1#2\relax{%
  \mathbb{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else^{#2}\fi
}
\def\ZZargs{[1][]}
\newcommand\makeZZ[1]{%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\z\z\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\ZZargs\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\ensuremath\expandafter{\expandafter
      \ZZstencil\z####1\relax}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\makeZZ{F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H}
\RR\ \RR[a+b]\ \ZZ\ \ZZ[(a+b)/2]\ $\HH\HH[x]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steven. I appreciate this instructive alternative to '\clist_map_inline:nn'

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `expl3` for the job, but differently from other answers using it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makenumberset}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { ##1##1 } { \numberset { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\numberset}{mo}
 {
  \ensuremath { \mathbb{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makenumberset{F,N,Z,Q,R,C,H}

\begin{document}

In text \RR\ and \RR[m+n]; also in math $\RR$ and $\RR[m+n]$.

In text \ZZ\ and \ZZ[m+n]; also in math $\FF$ and $\FF[m+n]$.

And also \numberset{A} or \numberset{A}[m+n].

\end{document}
```

Note the abstract command for the occasional letter.

[image]

Of course I'd ***not*** use `\ensuremath` that serves no real purpose. It's not much of a save being able to type `\RR` in text, while having to remember a following backslash sometimes. With `$\RR$` you don't have the problem.